# JQuery add/subtract value of button from price

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, var

I have a series of button with price values in them. I want to add/subtract the button values from a total value which is in s `span.quote-price`.

The below code works well and totals up the price but i want to adapt it if possible so that if the button isn't selected or doesn't have a class of selected then the figure isn't added.

At the moment, the price just keeps adding up even if the button has been deselected. Thanks for your help.

```js
var theTotal = 0;

$('button').click(function() {
  theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());
  $('span.quote-price').text("£" + theTotal.toFixed(2));
});

$('select').click(function() {
  theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());
  $('span.quote-price').text("£" + theTotal.toFixed(2));
});

$('button#reset').click(function() {
  $('span.quote-price').html("£0.00");
});

$('span.quote-price').text("£" + theTotal.toFixed(2));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="package_1" value="10.00" name="package_1">Package 1</button>
<button id="package_2" value="20.00" name="package_1">Package 2</button>
<button id="package_3" value="30.00" name="package_1">Package 3</button>

<p><span class="quote-price">0.00</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Can you also show your HTML and/or a working example?

Comment: would it suit your purposes to use checkboxes instead of buttons?

Comment: I need buttons unfortunately, for styling purposes. I've updated now wth html - thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a simpler pattern to have a single function which calculates the total which is called on the state change of the `button` or `select` element. Try this:

```
function updateTotal() {
    var total = 0;
    $('button.selected').each(function() {
        total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    total += parseFloat($('select').val());
    $('span.quote-price').text("£" + total.toFixed(2));
}

$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    updateTotal();
});
$('select').change(updateTotal);
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/0bu4v4pu/1/)

Comment: This works brilliantly - thanks. However, this '$('select').change(updateTotal);' doesnt seem to work my multiple select menus. How would i adapt this bit for 5 select menus?

Comment: The issue there is because multiple select menus provide the value as a comma delimited string, eg `10.00,20.00` which cannot be parsed to a float. You would need to `split()` that string and add up each value in a another loop.

Comment: Like so ... total += parseFloat($('select#1').val());
    $('span.quote-price').text("£" + total.toFixed(2));}
    total += parseFloat($('select#2').val());
    $('span.quote-price').text("£" + total.toFixed(2));}
    total += parseFloat($('select#3').val());
    $('span.quote-price').text("£" + total.toFixed(2));}

Answer (score 0):

something like this? i added class `.selected` css so you can keep track of what is adding up to the totals and what is not

pretty much the functionality goes like this (changes were made only to `$(button).click()` function:
-if clicked button has class `.selected`, then subtract value from total and then remove class.

-if clicked button does not have class `.selected`, then add value to total and add class.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var theTotal = 0;

    $('button').click(function() {
        console.log($(this).hasClass('selected'));
        if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            theTotal = Number(theTotal) - Number($(this).val());
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        }
        else {
            theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
        $('span.quote-price').text("£" + theTotal.toFixed(2));
    });

    $('select').click(function() {
        theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());
        $('span.quote-price').text("£" + theTotal.toFixed(2));
    });

    $('button#reset').click(function() {
        $('span.quote-price').html("£0.00");
    });

    $('span.quote-price').text("£" + theTotal.toFixed(2));
});
```

```css
.selected {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="package_1" value="10.00" name="package_1">Package 1</button>
<button id="package_2" value="20.00" name="package_1">Package 2</button>
<button id="package_3" value="30.00" name="package_1">Package 3</button>

<p><span class="quote-price">0.00</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a toggle for the class and a toggle for the amout. That should do the trick.

```js
var theTotal = 0;

$('button').click(function() {
  theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());
  $('span.quote-price').text("£" + theTotal.toFixed(2));
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  $(this).attr("value", ($(this).val() * -1));
});

$('span.quote-price').text("£" + theTotal.toFixed(2));
```

```css
button.selected { color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="package_1" value="10.00" name="package_1">Package 1</button>
<button id="package_2" value="20.00" name="package_1">Package 2</button>
<button id="package_3" value="30.00" name="package_1">Package 3</button>

<p><span class="quote-price">0.00</span>
</p>
```

I have removed the parts of the script that did not relate to your problem.